# How to parse JSON response that includes multiple objects

Tags: python, json, rest, api, jira

A REST API that I am calling returns multiple objects in a single JSON response. Using Python 2.7 I am trying to parse this response so that I can print some of these values for ALL objects in the response.

What would be the best way to extract this data from **all** objects given in the response from the REST API?

I want a list that includes the "key", "name", and "emailAddress" for each object in the JSON response.

This is how I did it for single objects in a response:

```
>>>> a = json.loads(response)
>>> print a.get(key), ";", a.get('name'), ";", a.get('emailAddress')
keyOne ; nameOne ; mailOne
```

For multiple objects I would want each object to have the key;name;email on displayed on a new line.

The response data is structured as followed:

```
[
  {
    "self": "https://example1.com",
    "key": "keyOne",
    "name": "nameOne",
    "emailAddress": "mailOne",
    "avatarUrls": {
      "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=1",
      "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=1",
      "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=1",
      "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=1"
    },
    "displayName": "displayNameOne",
    "active": true,
    "timeZone": "Europe",
    "locale": "en_UK"
  },
  {
    "self": "https://example2.com",
    "key": "keyTwo",
    "name": "nameTwo",
    "emailAddress": "mailTwo",
    "avatarUrls": {
      "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=2",
      "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=2",
      "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=2",
      "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=2"
    },
    "displayName": "displayNameTwo",
    "active": false,
    "timeZone": "Europe",
    "locale": "en_US"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the response list to get the values of the keys you want:

```
j_res = [
          {
            "self": "https://example1.com", 

             # rest of the response here

            "timeZone": "Europe",
            "locale": "en_US"
          }
        ]

for elem in j_res:
    print(elem.get('key', "Key does not exist"), elem.get('name', 'Name does not exist'), elem.get('emailAddress', 'emailAddress does not exist'))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
keyOne nameOne mailOne
keyTwo nameTwo mailTwo
```

**EDIT**:

If you want them in a list of tuple:

```
print([(elem.get('key', None), elem.get('name', None), elem.get('emailAddress', None)) for elem in j_res])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[('keyOne', 'nameOne', 'mailOne'), ('keyTwo', 'nameTwo', 'mailTwo')]
```

**EDIT 2**:

Since the response returns a boolean (`true`/`false`) instead of a string, a workaround for that could be to convert the response to a string and then replace the invalid booleans with the string, afterwards iterate of the list:

```
j_res = '''[
  {
    "self": "https://example1.com",
    "key": "keyOne",
    "name": "nameOne",
    "emailAddress": "mailOne",
    "avatarUrls": {
      "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=1",
      "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=1",
      "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=1",
      "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=1"
    },
    "displayName": "displayNameOne",
    "active": true,                      # notice this
    "timeZone": "Europe",
    "locale": "en_UK"
  },
  {
    "self": "https://example2.com",
    "key": "keyTwo",
    "name": "nameTwo",
    "emailAddress": "mailTwo",
    "avatarUrls": {
      "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=2",
      "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=2",
      "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=2",
      "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=2"
    },
    "displayName": "displayNameTwo",
    "active": false,                   # notice this
    "timeZone": "Europe",
    "locale": "en_US"
  }
]'''


from ast import literal_eval

res = literal_eval(j_res.replace("true","'true'").replace("false", "'false'"))    
print([(elem.get('key', None), elem.get('name', None), elem.get('emailAddress', None)) for elem in res])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[('keyOne', 'nameOne', 'mailOne'), ('keyTwo', 'nameTwo', 'mailTwo')]
```

Comment: The key for "Active" returns a boolean instead of a string. This results in `NameError: name 'true' is not defined`. Is there an easy way to fix this error without manually adjusting the data?

Comment: The response is received through a GET request to the API directly from a Python script. I checked the API documentation and it is a boolean by default.

Comment: @Falco no worries, just convert the response to a string and then follow what I showed in my second edit!

Comment: One question, do I manually need to add "" for every new object in the JSON response?

Comment: @Falco Nope, just convert the response you get to `str`

Answer (score 2):

The reponse is just an array of objects. You need to iterate over this array and print the keys that you are printing for one object.

```
resp = ...
for a in resp:
    print a.get(key), ";", a.get('name'), ";", a.get('emailAddress')
```