# How to parse JSON response that includes multiple JSON objects

Tags: python, json, rest

[How to parse JSON response that includes multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575374/how-to-parse-json-response-that-includes-multiple-objects)
with reference to above link, I am getting multiple JSON objects in response but unlike response in above link (which receives single array of multiple JSONs), I am getting multiple JSONs without the square brackets and comma between two JSONs

The response data is structured as follows:

```json
{
"self": "https://example1.com",
"key": "keyOne",
"name": "nameOne",
"emailAddress": "mailOne",
"avatarUrls": {
  "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=1",
  "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=1",
  "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=1",
  "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=1"
},
"displayName": "displayNameOne",
"active": true,
"timeZone": "Europe",
"locale": "en_UK"
}
{
"self": "https://example2.com",
"key": "keyTwo",
"name": "nameTwo",
"emailAddress": "mailTwo",
"avatarUrls": {
  "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=2",
  "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=2",
  "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=2",
  "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=2"
},
"displayName": "displayNameTwo",
"active": false,
"timeZone": "Europe",
"locale": "en_US"
}
```

I tried looping through rest API response, thought of enclosing response within square brackets but all failed.

[Parsing response with multiple json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77363207/parsing-response-with-multiple-json-objects)
I checked above link but here too but they have one JSON element in single line which is not the case with me.  How to address the task using Python please help.

Comment: This is NOT valid JSON. It's not even ndjson/jsonlines (given that each json object is not on one line)

Comment: Which API are you getting this from?

Comment: I think it's either something went wrong when you were getting the data or the service you are fetching from is giving you invalids data structure.  JSON or not, the data doesn't look like valid data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data contains multiple JSON objects. They can be separated by detecting a line containing just } and an adjacent line containing just {

Therefore:

```
data = '''
{
"self": "https://example1.com",
"key": "keyOne",
"name": "nameOne",
"emailAddress": "mailOne",
"avatarUrls": {
  "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=1",
  "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=1",
  "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=1",
  "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=1"
},
"displayName": "displayNameOne",
"active": true,
"timeZone": "Europe",
"locale": "en_UK"
}
{
"self": "https://example2.com",
"key": "keyTwo",
"name": "nameTwo",
"emailAddress": "mailTwo",
"avatarUrls": {
  "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=2",
  "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=2",
  "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=2",
  "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=2"
},
"displayName": "displayNameTwo",
"active": false,
"timeZone": "Europe",
"locale": "en_US"
}
'''
from json import loads, dumps

jlist = []
k = 0

for i, line in enumerate(lines := data.splitlines()):
    if i and line == "{" and lines[i-1] == "}":
        jlist.append(loads("".join(lines[k:i])))
        k = i

jlist.append(loads("".join(lines[k:])))

for j in jlist:
    print(dumps(j, indent=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its weird that something like an API responds with something that looks like JSON but isn't valid JSON.

Anyways, if the JSON structure follow the same structure, then you know that each item is 16 lines long so just split it on line 16 and you'll have 2 valid json objects. Something like this:

```py
import json

data = "" # your json

data_split = data.splitlines()
json_result = []
for data in range(0, len(data_split), 16):
    b = "".join(data_split[data:data+16])
    json_result.append(json.loads(b))

print(json_result)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a Function:

```
response = '''
{
"self": "https://example1.com",
"key": "keyOne",
"name": "nameOne",
"emailAddress": "mailOne",
"avatarUrls": {
  "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=1",
  "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=1",
  "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=1",
  "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=1"
},
"displayName": "displayNameOne",
"active": true,
"timeZone": "Europe",
"locale": "en_UK"
}
{
"self": "https://example2.com",
"key": "keyTwo",
"name": "nameTwo",
"emailAddress": "mailTwo",
"avatarUrls": {
  "48x48": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?avatarId=2",
  "24x24": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=2",
  "16x16": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=2",
  "32x32": "https://test.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=2"
},
"displayName": "displayNameTwo",
"active": false,
"timeZone": "Europe",
"locale": "en_US"
}
'''

import json

def parse_response(response):
    response = response.strip()
    json_strs = response.split('\n{\n"self":')
    json_strs = [json_strs[0]] + ['{\n"self":' + s for s in json_strs[1:]]
    json_array_str = '[' + ','.join(json_strs) + ']'
    return json.loads(json_array_str)

parsed_data = parse_response(response)

print(parsed_data)
```

Comment: Didn't but as far as i can remember should be fine !

Comment: This cannot be made to work as OP's data is not valid JSON

Comment: i just got on my pc and made it for you,i edited the Answer